# Upgrade a user's permissions in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

If I create a read-only user, but want to give them write access, how do I do that in CockroachDB?

Answer (score 1):

At any time you can simply grant a user new permissions via the `GRANT` family of SQL commands, as explained in the [documentation for `GRANT`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/grant.html).

For example, to grant the user `jordan` `INSERT` permissions on all tables in the `test` database, run the following command in a SQL shell:

`GRANT INSERT ON TABLE test.* TO jordan`